# Firebase Function Logs empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I am trying to have the following function from firebase run when a value is added to the notifications in my database. However I do not feel that the function is being triggered to run even though new values are being written in the path. The logs for the function remains empty.

Since I cannot add an image here is the best I can do to describe it. In the database we Notifications. Within Notifications, when someone tries to add a friend, it populates it with the user_id of that person who would receive the request. With in that persons user_id it then adds a randomly generated notification_id where in that part it has both the user who sent the request and the type of notification. Below is a little diagram

- Notifications
- --->user_id
- ------>notification_id
- --------->from
- --------->type

index.js

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {


 const user_id = event.params.user_id;
   const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

   console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', user_id);
  
 if(!event.data.val()){
    
     return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
  
 }
  
   const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');
  
   return deviceToken.then(result => {
      
       const token_id = result.val();
        
       const payload = {
            notification: {
                title : "Friend Request",
                body : "You-ve recieved a new Friend Request",
                icon : "default",
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

            console.log('This was the notification feature');

        });
    
    });

});
```

.runtimeconfig.json

```js
{
  "firebase": {
    "projectId": "lapitchat-c1aab",
    "databaseURL": "https://lapitchat-c1aab.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "lapitchat-c1aab.appspot.com",
    "cloudResourceLocation": "us-central"
  }
}
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.13.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Is there something that I am missing or any errors in my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// There is a new signature for onWrite
exports.sendNotification =
  functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      const user_id = context.params.user_id;
      const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!change.after.exists()) {
        console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database : ', notification_id);
        return null;
      }

      console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', user_id);

      return admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value')
        .then(result => {

          const token_id = result.val();

          const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: "Friend Request",
              body: "You-ve recieved a new Friend Request",
              icon: "default"
            }
          };

          return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log('This was the notification feature');
          return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

---

Need to enable FCM message sending API:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Search for FCM and enable on your project

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the code you sent and enabling FCM however there are still no logs. I can see in the database how there is a new notification being written.